# Output of two dimensional array program

Tags: c, arrays

What would be the output of the following program?

```
main( ) 
{ 
 int n[3][3] = { 
 2, 4, 3, 
 6, 8, 5, 
 3, 5, 1 
 } ; 
 printf ( "\n%d %d %d", *n, n[3][3], n[2][2] ) ; 
}
```

I thought it will print out-

`address of first element, then 1 and then 8`

But somehow, it is printing out garbage values for first two and then `1 for n[2][2]`. Can anybody provide detailed explanation about this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: Meaning? Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Indices of arrays in C (and in many languages that sprang from C) start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Yeah that thing I know but then why it is printing out garbage values for first two print statement?

Comment: If you know that, then why are you trying to print out `n[3][3]`?

Comment: It's in the Let us C book. So I was trying to understand this program.

Comment: May I recommend a book of apparently higher quality such as [Practical C Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565923065.do), [Head First C](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920015482.do), or [The C Programming Language (aka K&R)](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628)?

Comment: Yeah, now I understand that part. What about `*n`, that thing is confusing me?

Comment: Well, what does `*n` print out?

Comment: Some garbage value I believe.

Comment: `*n` is printing out the address of the first row in the array; `n[3][3]` is accessing a long way out of bounds (the array indexes go from 0 to 2).  If you're on a 64-bit system, you might see garbage for the third value too; on a 32-bit system, you should see 1 for the last value.

Comment: I agree with jack, if your book told you to run this code you should burn it.  The authors can't be upset, they should know running this sort of code (undefined behavior) can cause anything to happen.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks Jonathan for the suggestion. So `*n` means the address of first element in the first row? right?

Comment: Although this example is poor, don't confuse seeing the address of a value as garbage. Depending on how you print them out, they can look strange.

Comment: Strictly, the type of `*n` is `int (*)[3]` (meaning, pointer to an array of `int` of size 3, if my brain isn't fried which isn't guaranteed at this time of night); this is a different type from `&n[0][0]`, but the value is the same.  You could establish the difference by printing `*n+1` and `&n[0][0]+1`, which would give you two different values.  You should be using `#include <inttypes.h>` and a `(uintptr_t)` cast and `"0x%.08" PRIXPTR` or thereabouts to format the address, too; or `%p` and a `(void *)` cast, though the void pointer cast is indisputably the ultimate in fussiness.

Comment: @xaxxon you mean whose answer he changed three accepted answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Study and learn.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static void print_address0(const char *tag, const void *addr, const void *addr_1);
static void print_address1(const char *fmt, int i, const void *addr, const void *addr_1);
static void print_address2(const char *fmt, int i, int j, const void *addr, const void *addr_1);

#define ANALYZE_0(val)            print_address0(#val, val, (val)+1)
#define ANALYZE_1(fmt, i, val)    print_address1(fmt, i, val, (val)+1)
#define ANALYZE_2(fmt, i, j, val) print_address2(fmt, i, j, val, (val)+1)

int main(void)
{
    int n[3][3] =
    {
        { 2, 4, 3 },
        { 6, 8, 5 },
        { 3, 5, 1 },
    };

    ANALYZE_0(&n);
    ANALYZE_0( n);
    ANALYZE_0(*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ANALYZE_1("*(n+%d)", i, *(n+i));
        ANALYZE_1("n[%d]",   i, n[i]);
        ANALYZE_1("&n[%d]",  i, &n[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            ANALYZE_2("&n[%d][%d]", i, j, &n[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void print_address0(const char *tag, const void *addr, const void *addr_1)
{
    printf("%-8s = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR, tag, (uintptr_t)addr);
    char buffer[16];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "(%s)+1", tag);
    printf("; %-12s = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", buffer, (uintptr_t)addr_1);
}

static void print_address1(const char *fmt, int i, const void *addr, const void *addr_1)
{
    char buffer[16];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, i);
    print_address0(buffer, addr, addr_1);
}

static void print_address2(const char *fmt, int i, int j, const void *addr, const void *addr_1)
{
    char buffer[16];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, i, j);
    print_address0(buffer, addr, addr_1);
}
```

Output from GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.3 (64-bit compilation):

```
&n       = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (&n)+1       = 0x7FFF5F2D74E4
n        = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (n)+1        = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC
*n       = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (*n)+1       = 0x7FFF5F2D74C4
*(n+0)   = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (*(n+0))+1   = 0x7FFF5F2D74C4
n[0]     = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (n[0])+1     = 0x7FFF5F2D74C4
&n[0]    = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (&n[0])+1    = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC
&n[0][0] = 0x7FFF5F2D74C0; (&n[0][0])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74C4
&n[0][1] = 0x7FFF5F2D74C4; (&n[0][1])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74C8
&n[0][2] = 0x7FFF5F2D74C8; (&n[0][2])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC
*(n+1)   = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC; (*(n+1))+1   = 0x7FFF5F2D74D0
n[1]     = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC; (n[1])+1     = 0x7FFF5F2D74D0
&n[1]    = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC; (&n[1])+1    = 0x7FFF5F2D74D8
&n[1][0] = 0x7FFF5F2D74CC; (&n[1][0])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74D0
&n[1][1] = 0x7FFF5F2D74D0; (&n[1][1])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74D4
&n[1][2] = 0x7FFF5F2D74D4; (&n[1][2])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74D8
*(n+2)   = 0x7FFF5F2D74D8; (*(n+2))+1   = 0x7FFF5F2D74DC
n[2]     = 0x7FFF5F2D74D8; (n[2])+1     = 0x7FFF5F2D74DC
&n[2]    = 0x7FFF5F2D74D8; (&n[2])+1    = 0x7FFF5F2D74E4
&n[2][0] = 0x7FFF5F2D74D8; (&n[2][0])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74DC
&n[2][1] = 0x7FFF5F2D74DC; (&n[2][1])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74E0
&n[2][2] = 0x7FFF5F2D74E0; (&n[2][2])+1 = 0x7FFF5F2D74E4
```

The output shows a lot of variations on the them of the addresses associated with elements of the array.  Each line shows the address of one expression, and the address of the same expression plus one (the difference indicates the size of the object pointed at, therefore).

The code uses the macros to encapsulate repeated code so that the `main()` program is clearer.  The other three functions handle formatting of the strings and values to be printed.  The code is a little intricate, but clearer like this than written without the functions (I tried it; the details of what was being analyzed were completely lost in the necessary code).

Comment: could you please explain this " If you're on a 64-bit system, you might see garbage for the third value too;" that you state in one of your comments above? i dint quite understand

Comment: The `printf()` statement I said that about was: `printf("\n%d %d %d", *n, n[3][3], n[2][2]);`. Suppose that you have 8-bit bytes (that's normal), and `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(void *) == 8` (a standard 64-bit compilation). Then 8 bytes are pushed on the stack by `*n`, followed by 4 bytes for `n[3][3]`, and another 4 bytes for `n[2][2]`. However, `printf()` is told to expect 3 4-byte integers, so it will read 4 bytes of `*n` for the first `%d`, the other 4 bytes of `*n` for the second `%d`, and the out-of-bounds value `n[3][3]` for the third `%d`, so the third value would be garbage too.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect `*n` to give first value of the matrix that's wrong its for one dimensional arrays. `**n` prints the first value of the matrix. So, `*n` gives the address of the first element.

**EDIT:** So `n` and `*n` give the same value in this respect for **2d array**

Indices start from 0 in `C` language. So, when you use `n[2][2]` it gives the value of 3rd row and 3rd column that is `1`.

When you use **`n[3][3]`** you are exceeding your limits declared for the matrix. You are trying to acess 4th row 4th column which you haven't declared and is an error that's not reported by `C`.

Summary

```
*n=address of first element of the matrix
**n=value of first element of matrix=2
n[2][2]=value of 3*3 cell=1
n[3][3]=value of 4*4 cell=garbage in your case
```

I hope you understand....

Comment: @xaxxon I know *n points to the beginning of the 2d array but it doesn't dereference the value I hope...

Comment: So what I'm seeing is that both n and *n are the same thing and **n is the value of the first element.  A bit weird, but whatever :)  Deleting my other comment.

Comment: You should update your comment that n and *n are the same thing, I think.  on my mac,   printf("%p %p %d\n", n, *n, **n); gives: 0x7fff553dd8a8 0x7fff553dd8a8 2

Comment: @xaxxon yes I too got the same results and I tested before answering but I didn't highlight it....I will update my answer however

Comment: `n` and `*n` are not the same. their values may be but not their type. its just like this `double d = 1;` `int i = 1`; `i` and `d` are `1` that doesnt make them the same. `n` is an array of 3 elements of each of type `int[3]` and `*n` is an array of `3 ints`.

Comment: @Koushik of course, I mean the values... and I specified that it is for "2d array", I  updated accordingly stating values for more clarity

Comment: for that reason i think even `&n` will be same as `n` or `*n`

Comment: @Koushik the asker wondered why *n gave him garbage...I'm sure he expected first cell's value so I pointed him not to confuse between *n and **n that's it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31021/discussion-between-pinkpanther-and-koushik)

Comment: @Koushik they're a lot more alike than those examples you gave.  It has the exact same binary representation

Comment: @xaxxon you mean binary representation of n and *n? i dont disagree with the value being same but not their types. binary representation of char = 1 and int = 1 are also same but they are different types.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

address of row0 , garbage value, 1

*n givess the address of first row;
so  *n , n[0] or n+0, &n[0] all gives same answer.

arr[3][3] is out of bounds as indexes in c starts from 0.

```
int arr[]={0,1,2};
```

so here arr[0]=0, arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhu5q.jpg)=1, and arr[2]=2

thats why garbage value.

finally as said above arr[2][2] returns 1. This is a sample memory mapping or 2 dimensional array allocated dynamically.

[image: This is sample array allocated dynamically]

if array defined static it'll like

```
   0    1    2    3   4   5      6  7  8 
|              |             |             |
|[0][0]        |             |             |
|--row 0-------| row 1       |----row 1----|
```

Comment: is * a valid operation on an array?  Also, why would it be the address of the first row?  You don't need double pointers for 2d arrayI think you're getting arrays and pointers confused.  They're not the same.

Comment: downvote is great it they let me know what i'm missing or wrong. [everyone can learn [me!]]

Comment: if you call sizeof on an array, is there any overhead for additional levels of pointer indirection such that a dereferenced pointer to a 2d array could give you a pointer?  (there's not)  Same reason you can't pass a 2d array to a function and have it still be a 2d array.  You're confusing this with an array of pointers each with an array hanging off of that, which you can pass around, but that is not a native 2D C array

Comment: No.  If I could give you more downvotes I would.  This is terribly wrong.  Your graphic is wrong.  Build the 3x3 2D array and call sizeof on it.  It doesn't give you the size of the graphic you added because that's not a C 2D array.

Comment: i don't get it. [please explain even i'm beginner]

Comment: The diagram is wonderful except that it is also wrong.  The elements of the array are laid out as shown from arr[0][0] to arr[2][2], but the entries shown for arr[0], arr[1] and arr[2] are bogus, and likewise for arr itself.  Note that the value of arr is the same as the value of arr[0] (but the types are different), and are also the same as &arr[0][0] (but the types are different again).

Comment: what you wrote is when you say` int**foo=malloc(sizeof(int*)*3); for i = 0; i < 3; i++{foo[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*3;}` -- but that is NOT a native C 2D array

Comment: An array in C uses EXACTLY as much memory as the sum of the actual data elements.  so a 3x3 array uses 9*sizeof(element).  You can easily prove this to yourself

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: even for dynamic array[][]?

Comment: all you have to do is run sizeof on it and see for yourself

Comment: No; a 2D dynamically allocated array is a very different construct, and your diagram is more or less correct for that.  But the array in the question is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are we talking about VLAs now?  I just wrote some code I *THINK* makes a vla and it was still the mathematical minimum amount of space.  and n and *n are the same.  VLA you make from passing in an integral parameter and parameterizing the array from that, right?

Comment: @xaxxon: No; VLAs are just a special case of the same sort of array as analyzed in the question.  Dineshkumar: See my answer, which is actually as much addressed to you as it is to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In C array indexes start at `0`, not at `1`. That is why you are getting unexpected results.

If you want to print the `2 X 2` and `3 X 3` elements in your matrix, You should print `arr[1][1]` and `arr[2][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays first index stars from arr[0][0] and there is no value at arr[3][3] in the given input

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C start with 0 index. i.e. in your case:

- n[0][0] = 2
- n[0][1] = 4
- n[0][2] = 3
- n[1][0] = 6
- n[1][1] = 8
- n[1][2] = 5
- n[2][0] = 3
- n[2][1] = 5
- n[2][2] = 1

n[2][2] is the maximum location of your array. That is why when you try to print n[3][3], you get some garbage value.

and *n will print the starting address of the array.